# How to filter a list by the values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list which looks like this:

```
  my_list=
    [
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'GE' ],
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'MUN' ]
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Spain', 'ES' ]
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Spain', 'MAD' ]
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC France', 'FR' ]
    ]
```

I also a have a variable and a dictionary which look like this:

```
country_to_cath = 'GE'

my_dict = {'CC Germany': 'Ge', 'CC Spain': 'Es', 'CC France': 'Fr'}
```

I'm trying to filter `my_list` based on the `country_to_catch` variable, the variable says `GE`. If I look where `GE` stands for in `my_dict`, I see `CC Germany`(need to make it upper). So I need to filter all the records with `CC Germany` from `my_list`

**this is my code:**

```
country_to_catch = 'GE'
for row in my_list:
    if row[3] == my_dict[country_to_catch]:
       print(row)
```

**my desired output:**

```
   'C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'GE' 
   'C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'MUN'
```

**my current output:**

```
 KeyError: 'GE'
```

Comment: there are a lot of abnormalities with your code. lookup is reversed and in different cases(dictionary contains `Ge` and you are looking for `GE`).

Comment: `[k for k in my_dict if my_dict[k].upper()==country_to_catch.upper()][0]` for reverse lookup.

Comment: @MeowCat2012 thats a list comprehension? How would that look in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse your dictionary for your code to work. Also take in account the uppercases.

```
my_list=[
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'GE' ],
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'MUN' ],
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Spain', 'ES' ],
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Sppain', 'MAD' ],
    ['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC France', 'FR' ]
    ]

my_dict = {'CC Germany': 'Ge', 'CC Spain': 'Es', 'CC France': 'Fr'}
reversed_dictionary = {value : key for (key, value) in my_dict.items()}
country_to_catch = 'Ge'

for row in my_list:
  
    if row[3] == reversed_dictionary[country_to_catch]:
       print(row)

#['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'GE']
#['C150', 'Audi', 'P1', 'CC Germany', 'MUN']
```